# Passing along a hidden formvalue with Dropzone in ASP.NET Mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dropzone.js

Just started using Dropzone and so far it looks really good. I have the backend-functionality to handle the upload itself, but when debugging I've noticed that the action never gets hit. This is due to the fact that my form includes a hidden input to pass along a required id (for the action that does the uploading).
This is my form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "UnitSummary", FormMethod.Post, new
{
    enctype = "multipart/form-data",
    id = "imgUpload",
    @class = "dropzone"
}))
{
    <div class="fallback">
        <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
        <input type="hidden" name="unitId" value="@Model.ViewUnitContract.Id"/>
    </div>
}
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Dropzone
        Dropzone.options.imgUpload = {
            paramName: "file", // Must match the name of the HttpPostedFileBase argument that the Upload action expects.
            acceptedFiles: "image/*" // Accept images only
        };
    });
</script>
```

And here's my action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file, int unitId)
{
    ...
}
```

Now, if I remove the "int unitId" parameter, this action triggered. The only problem is that I actually need that id :)

Comment: Have you tried just a normal `<form>` tag and appending the unitId as a querystring? `<form action="/UnitSummary/UploadFile?unitId=@Model.ViewUnitContract.Id" method="post"></form>`

Comment: Thanks @RGraham! That works! :) Feel free to add it as an answer for me to accept!

Comment: Better if you add the answer yourself from the code you used to fix the issue. Earn yourself a badge too :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved by using the following form:

```
<form action="/UnitSummary/UploadFile?unitId=@Model.ViewUnitContract.Id" class="dropzone" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="imgUpload" method="post">
    <div class="fallback">
        <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Controller action and js stayed the same.